# In Restful web services how to get username or password programmatically (basic authentication)

Tags: rest, ejb-3.0, restful-authentication, basic-authentication

I have restful web services in a Java EE application (ejb3) running on jboss. And do not know how to get username or password programmatically, like when service method is called I want to be able to get this user principals as smilar to jaxws

```
webServiceContext.getUserPrincipal().getName()
```

or

```
(httpServletRequest) <-- request.getUserPrincipal()
```

I would be glad to hear the solutions, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SOLVED] 
I have found the solution, here it is;

Use

```
@Context
 protected SecurityContext sc;
```

Or

```
Public TestResponse test(@Context SecurityContext sc){
   ..
   sc.getUserPrincipal.getName() //will return username
}
```

Comment: Did you also got the password via an injected context??

Comment: It was ages ago actually but as I remember, yes, I was able to get both username and password! Maybe sc.getUserPrincipal.getPassword()?